# How to get directory size and modification date time using the same command in hdfs shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I need to get the modification datetime and the directory size using the same command using hdfs cli. Currently I am running 2 separate commands and manually merging the rows. Is there a way to do this directly?

The commands I am using are:

1. `hdfs dfs -du -h ~/tmp` to get the size
2. `hdfs dfs -ls ~/tmp` to get the modification date

Answer (score 0):

Two commands are required, just like in Linux

You're more than welcome to create your own shell script that runs both commands after one another that accepts the folder as input